# Proving that equivalence class has invertible element in residue class.

Tags: solution-verification, euclidean-algorithm

**Let** $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ **a number with characteristic**

$$
\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \: 1 = xz + yn
$$

**Show that** $[z]_n$ **in** $(\mathbb{Z}_n, *)$ **is invertibel. Figure out invertibel element also.**

$* = $ Multiplication operation.

**My proof:**

Using $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \: 1 = xz + yn$, using Euclidean algorithm it is true that $ggT(z,n) = 1$.

$\Rightarrow 1 \equiv xz \mod n$

So is $x \mod n$ inverse to z.

Does this proof suffice?

Comment: looks okay to me.